# Why my dropdown menu is effecting main menu?

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I have items in menu. And in one menu has drop down. I added in general way. But not working. It is breaking other menus.

[image]

See the menu adding in wordpress.

[image]

Comment: Shortcodes aren't usually allowed in menus. It's probably an issue with a plugin you're using - possibly the theme.

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/hotel-zante-hotel-wordpress-theme/22325268 using this theme. Shortcodes means??

Comment: In your screen shot of the menu editing screen, if you look on the right side of each item, everything is a "Custom Link" except one item - the next-to-the-last item, which is showing up as "(Untitled) Shortcode)". I would suggest removing that item to see if it resolves the problem. You could also disable all of your plugins to see if that solves it, and if so, it would mean your theme is at fault and you can contact the author directly for support.

Comment: I have deleted the shortcode. But need to undo the changes. But I can't get the option. Please help me.

Comment: Now, there is no revision in wp?!!

Comment: Right, menus don't have revisions or undos. Do you make backups regularly? Restoring a backup would be the easiest way to get back to where you were. Many hosts offer backups even retroactively - i.e. if you pay for it today you get backups that were made this past week - so you may want to check with them.

Comment: I have a backup. But where the menu generally situated?

Comment: Menu items are stored in the posts table.